# bootstrap navbar with centered nav-brand

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

i am trying to make a responsive navbar with the nav-brand in center of it. the problem is when it is collapsed it does not show the right < ul > of the menu and sometimes it do but on weird way.
i want to the collapsed navbar to show the nav item below the nav-brand.

my navbar:
https://codepen.io/0xSimo/pen/MWJNaYP

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>ChriDarek</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" >

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-lg-1 order-3" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link ">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Buy</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Rent</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Sell</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <a href="" class="navbar-brand text-white mx-2 order-1">
            <h2 class="d-inline align-middle"><strong>centerLogo</strong></h2>
        </a>

        <button class="order-2 navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="text-white fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-lg-3 order-4" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>



<script src="{{asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-nav .navbar-brand {
  color: #efefef;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding-left: 0.7rem;
  padding-right: 0.7rem;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item a,
.navbar-nav .nav-item button {
  color: #efefef;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background: #56ace3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navbar-toggler button uses the data-target to identify the items to include in the collapsed menu for mobile screens.

If you want two (or more) list of links included in the menu on small screens, switch from using an id (ids have to be unique – you can use the same id again) to using a class and apply the same class to each list.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    body {
        margin-top: 75px;
    }

    .navbar {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar-nav .navbar-brand {
        color: #efefef;
    }

    .navbar-nav .nav-item {
        font-size: 1.3rem;
        padding-left: 0.7rem;
        padding-right: 0.7rem;
    }

    .navbar-nav .nav-item a,
    .navbar-nav .nav-item button {
        color: #efefef;
    }

    .nav-item:hover {
        background: #f7f7f7;
    }

    .nav-item:hover {
        background: #56ace3;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-lg-1 order-3 navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link ">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Buy</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Rent</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Sell</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <a href="" class="navbar-brand text-white mx-2 order-1">
            <h2 class="d-inline align-middle"><strong>centerLogo</strong></h2>
        </a>

        <button class="order-2 navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="text-white fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-lg-3 order-4 navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item py-1">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And rather than using Codepen, it's easiest if you use the snippet tool.